# Pandas: How do I access other elements in a row if I only know an element in a row of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

For example in the data frame:

```
Gyroscope   448083  -0.05965481 -0.26418558 -0.017044231
Gyroscope   448338  -0.033023197    -0.18002969 -0.011717909
Gyroscope   448340  -0.052197956    -0.17470336 -0.049002163
Gyroscope   448341  -0.03834952 -0.16937704 -0.034088463
```

I know elements in the second column, but I want to pull out the last three elements.

`Interval` is a tuple where I know the timestamp to start and end at, but those values may not be in the data frame. 
If my `interval[0]` variable was `448075` and my `interval[1]` variable was `448345`, how do I access all the elements from the `3rd`, `4th`, and `5th` columns of the rows with column 1 values between `interval[0]` and `interval[1]`?

I try to find the closest values to `interval[0]` and `interval[1]` in the actual `DataFrame`.

```
start = np.abs(merge.iloc[:, 1] - i[0]).argmin()
end = np.abs(merge.iloc[:, 1] - i[1]).argmin()

for j in range(start, end):
    gyro.append((merge.iloc[:, j][2], merge.iloc[:, j][3], merge.iloc[:, j][4])) if merge.iloc[:, j][0] == 'Gyroscope' \
        else acc.append((merge.iloc[:, j][2], merge.iloc[:, j][3], merge.iloc[:, j][4]))
```

Then, using the range of numbers in the interval, I attempt to pull out the last three entries in each row.

`gyro` and `acc` are the lists I'm appending the last three entries in the relevant rows to.

`merge.head()` returns

```
            Gyroscope    448083  -0.05965481  -0.26418558  -0.017044231
0           Gyroscope  448338.0    -0.033023    -0.180030     -0.011718
1  LinearAcceleration  448339.0    -0.048183    -0.427365     -0.019752
2           Gyroscope  448340.0    -0.052198    -0.174703     -0.049002
3  LinearAcceleration  448340.0     0.168791    -0.166547     -0.136918
4           Gyroscope  448341.0    -0.038350    -0.169377     -0.034088
```

Basically, I want to index based on the range of second column values and iterate through that.

Comment: Does your dataframe have column names? Can you show your `merge.head()`?

Comment: It does not have column names.